# Fullscreen on an Android device with objects off stage

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm trying to put an AS3 "Flappy bird" example on my Android device but I can't put it in fullscreen and I don't understand why..

On the Adobe Flash pro emulator, the game is in fullScreen mode :

[Image1](http://hpics.li/261a385)

But on my Android device it's like that :

[Image2](http://hpics.li/1d253d7)

I think it is because I've got objects off stage...

Do you know, how can I put the game on fullscreen mode on my Android device ?

Thank you,

---

I've tried :

```
public function Main() {
stage.stageWidth=Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
stage.stageHeight=Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
  trace("fullscreen");
  }
```

But still not working....

Answer (score 1):

In your app.xml file for this project do you see  `<fullScreen>true</fullScreen>` after `<initialWindow>` If not, write it in, exactly as shown, and publish to your Android device using ADT.

Answer (score 0):

On mobile devices, "fullscreen" refers to whether or not the black status bar shows.

Set your swf to display without any scaling:

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT; 
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```